# Facebook Login Popup Blocked by Browsers

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am very new to javascript, really dont understand how to do, the Facebook login still blocked by popup blocker in any browsers

I place this code to a file fbapp1.php

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'myappid', // App ID
        channelUrl : '//example.com/fbapp1.php', // Channel File
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });
    // this shouldn't be called directly, but instead should be initiated with a user click event
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            // document.write ('Access Token: ' + response.authResponse.accessToken);
            window.location = 'https://example.com/fbapp2.php?access_token=' + response.authResponse.accessToken;
        } else {
            alert ('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
    });
};
// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
</script>
```

And to open this file i am using simple html href code in another page

```
<a href="https://example.com/fbapp1.php" target="_blank">"Pulsa Fortune App"</a>
```

But the Facebook login popup always blocked by the browsers. The code above already told this thing, but i dont know what its mean?

> this shouldn't be called directly, but instead should be initiated
>   with a user click event

Please tell me how my code should be?

Answer (score 3):

Do not call `FB.login` in an asynchronous callback function - `fbAsyncInit` is asynchronous. You have to call it on user interaction or browsers will block it for a good reason.

Example:

```
document.getElementById('loginBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    //do the login
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            //user just authorized your app
            document.getElementById('loginBtn').style.display = 'none';
            getUserData();
        }
    }, {scope: 'email,public_profile', return_scopes: true});
}, false);
```

Source: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: just create a div with the id "loginBtn"...it´s a simple click event listener, not sure what else there is to say, to be honest.